# Regular expression in JavaScript to match turkish characters

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I am using this code:

```
var icerik = $(this).val();
var kelime = /#(\w+)/ig;
var isim = icerik.match(kelime);
```

I am doing ajax process, example: `#bursa` is working, but `#büşra` isn't working, It isn't posting after the b.

https://jsfiddle.net/6mo9cyv5/

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the flag *g*.

```
var kelime = /#(\w+)/i;

console.log( kelime.test('#bursa') );
console.log( kelime.test('#büşra') );
```

> The "g" flag indicates that the regular expression should be tested
>   against all possible matches in a string.

It means that after the first match, it will save a "cursor" where it has found it. So if you try to match another string, it will start from that "cursor" point. Remove the *g* flag and it will start from the beginning each time.

--

**Edit**:

Use this: https://jsfiddle.net/afqm9uaa/

```
var kelime = /#[^\d]+/i;
$('#gonderi').on('input',function(){
    var icerik = $(this).val();
    var isim = icerik.match(kelime);
    var deger = "isim="+isim;

    if(isim && isim.length > 0) {
        $('#sonuc').html(isim[0]);  
    }
});
```

The patter was selecting \w+ (word character) which according to: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_wordchar.asp

> A word character is a character from a-z, A-Z, 0-9, including the _ (underscore) character.

So *bursa* matches, but *büşra* does not. Because that, I have changed it to [^\d] "anything but numbers". If you want numbers, you can use just:

```
var kelime = /#.+/i;
```

*.* means "anything".

--

If you want to get the word after the # character, you should use:

```
var result = icerik.substr(1); //Extracts # character
```

In that situation, I would simplify your code to this: https://jsfiddle.net/5wo6w3ev/2/

```
var kelime = /#.+/i;
$('#gonderi').on('input',function(){
    var icerik = $(this).val();
    if (kelime.test(icerik)) {
        var word = icerik.substr(1);

        $('#sonuc').html( word );  
    }
});
```

Comment: is it var kelime = /#(\w+)/i; ?

Comment: Yes, removing the *g* flag would match both. What do you mean by posting?

Comment: var kelime = /#(\w+)/i;
        $('#gonderi').on('keyup',function(){
            var icerik = $(this).val();
            var isim = icerik.match(kelime);
            var deger = "isim="+isim;
            
            if(isim.length > 0)
            {
                $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url:"islem.php",
                   data:deger,
                   success: function(e){
        });

Comment: Your questions is about ajax or javascript regex? It is not clear. Don't comment code but edit your question completing it. I suggest you to use https://jsfiddle.net/ to show your problem (so people can reproduce it). Otherwise none could help you.